# Complex analysis Laurent series of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

How to find the Laurent series of function \begin{equation} f(z)=\frac{z-2}{z^n(z-1)} , 0<|z|<1? \end{equation}
I understand that this Laurent series will converge since $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ except in points $0$ and $1$ which are excluded by the the given condition. Also, function $\frac{1}{z^n}$ is already expanded, but how to proceed from there?

Comment: $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^n} (2-z) \frac{1}{1-z}$ ... do you know the geometric series?

Comment: $$\frac{z-2}{(z-1) z^n}=\frac{2}{z^n}+\frac{1}{z^{n-1}}+\frac{1}{z^{n-2}}+\frac{1}{z^{n-3}}+\ldots=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } (2-z) z^{k-n}$$